# Configuring AWS Worker Tier App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have a rails application that is hosted on ASW Elastic Beanstalk (Worker Tier) and I want to set up a regular mailer shot. I have included the cron.yaml file at the root of my application which looks like the following.

cron.yaml

```js
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "test-email"
   url: "/schedule/send_test_email"
   schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
```

From rake routes

POST   /schedule/send_test_email(.:format) schedule#send_test_email

The API endpoint I am posting to

```js
def send_test_email
  Merchant.test_production_email
  render json: nil, status: :ok
end
```

And from the logs

```js
-------------------------------------
/var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log
-------------------------------------
2015-10-23T07:09:59Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/schedule/send_test_email]
2015-10-23T07:09:59Z http-err: 257fb276-d39e-4068-baf0-9106434674c5 (1) 502 - 0.004
2015-10-23T07:10:01Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/schedule/send_test_email]
2015-10-23T07:10:01Z http-err: 257fb276-d39e-4068-baf0-9106434674c5 (2) 502 - 0.007
2015-10-23T07:10:03Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/schedule/send_test_email]
2015-10-23T07:10:03Z http-err: 257fb276-d39e-4068-baf0-9106434674c5 (3) 502 - 0.004
2015-10-23T07:10:05Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/schedule/send_test_email]
```

HTTP request posted locally to localhost:3000/schedule/send_test_email return 200.

Amazons troubleshooting on 502 Bad Gateway

Description: Indicates that the load balancer was unable to parse the response sent from a registered instance.

Cause: Malformed response from the instance or potentially an issue with the load balancer.

Solution: Verify that the response being sent from the instance conforms to HTTP specifications.

I don't really know what this problem is and how to debug it. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I solved this. It was actually a problem with a missing secret_token. Added

Comment: secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %> to secrets.yml and then used commands rake secret to generate a secret token and then eb setenv  SECRET_TOKEN=******* to set it, then eb deploy and then it works!!

Comment: please answer your own question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. It was actually a problem with a missing secret_token.

secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %> to secrets.yml and then used commands rake secret to generate a secret token and then eb setenv SECRET_TOKEN=******* to set it, then eb deploy and then it works!!